# Comparing overlap with different SRIDs in MSSQL

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server-spatial

I am sourcing our GIS data (ESRI ArcGIS) into a data warehouse for reporting. I am trying to join our sites in Table_A (with a point geometry column) to our markets in Table_B (with a polygon geometry column) by using the STContains() function. However, I found that these two columns are using different SRIDs (4326 and 4269 respectively) so the function will not work. I've done a lot of reading, and found that SQL Server has no transform function. So I used the .STAsText() function to store the text and STGeomFromText function to recreate the geometry, but this time matching the SRIDs. Now the STContains() function returns 1 that they do overlap as expected. My concern is I don't fully understand the impact of changing this SRID. By doing so, did I shift the point/polygon from where it should be on the map? Is what I'm doing a valid solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post, and found that while it does shift the coordinate system it is only about a meter's worth. This is good enough for us.

[Is re-projection needed from SRID 4326 (WGS 84) to 4269 (NAD 83)SRID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170839/is-re-projection-needed-from-srid-4326-wgs-84-to-4269-nad-83srid)

I posted this question before my account was fully setup...not sure how to mark it as answered as the question is not tied to my account, but rather user83883.

Comment: You can merge your accounts, see this help page: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts