# How do I get all geometries within area using Google Maps API info?

Tags: postgis, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API. My `google.maps.Map` object is stored in variable `GLOBAL_map`. I have the following code:

```
var bounds= GLOBAL_map.getBounds();
var sw=     bounds.getSouthWest();
var ne=     bounds.getNorthEast();
var lngW=   sw.lng();
var latS=   sw.lat();
var lngE=   ne.lng();
var latN=   ne.lat();
var obj=    {
    lngW: lngW,
    latS: latS,
    lngE: lngE,
    latN: latN
};
console.log(obj);
```

Here's what `obj` can look like:

```
{
  latN: 47.66808688012437,
  latS: 47.637501470799144,
  lngE: -117.40694335937502,
  lngW: -117.43440917968752,
}
```

I have PostGIS table with a geometry column of multipolygons, SRID 4269. How can I use the info from the Google Maps object to make a PostGIS query that returns rows within the map's north, east, south, and west points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have PostGIS table with a geometry column of multipolygons, SRID 4269.

Google maps returns all results in SRID 4326. So you need to first either.

- [`ST_Transform()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) your input coordinates to 4326 on the table.
- Create an index on the result of the `ST_Transform`.

Let's assume the latter.

```
CREATE INDEX ON myTable USING GIST (ST_Transform(myGeom, 4326));
VACUUM ANALYZE myTable;
```

Then what you can do is, is build a bounding box with [`ST_MakeEnvelope`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html), and run the query. The end query will look something like,

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) && ST_Transform(myTable.geom,4326);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's OK to lie to PostGIS.

I'll assume that, since you're working with Google Maps, you don't need survey-level accuracy. In that case, I would just tell PostGIS Google Maps coordinates are in `EPSG:4269`. The differences between `EPSG:4269` and  the `EPSG:4326` coordinates provided by Google are, for most applications, negligeable. (See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/170854/18189 for a discussion.)

Your query, then, is just:

`SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(lngW, latS, lngE, latN, 4269), 4269))`