# Projection between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4269 using pyproj does nothing

Tags: python, coordinate-system, datum, pyproj

According to this quite thorough answer :

[Is re-projection needed from SRID 4326 (WGS 84) to SRID 4269 (NAD 83)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170839/is-re-projection-needed-from-srid-4326-wgs-84-to-srid-4269-nad-83)

the crs EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4269 are slightly different, due to a difference in one of the semi-axis of the reference ellipsoids (small difference) and also to a shift in the origin of the NAD83 Datum used in 4269.

However, when using pyproj (python 3.8.8 and pyproj 3.0.1 on windows) to project a point from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:4269, I obtain the exact same lat/lon :

```
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform

crs_4326 = CRS("EPSG:4326")
crs_4269 = CRS("EPSG:4269")

transformer_4326_to_4269 = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from=crs_4326, crs_to=crs_4269).transform
p = Point(-118,33)  # some position in California
p1 = transform(transformer_4326_to_4269, p)

print(p)  # returns POINT (-118 33)
print(p1) # also returns POINT (-118 33) !
```

I am quite confused as I was expecting a (rather small) difference.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304231/2856

Comment: I hadn't seen this link thanks. However, the answer provided is quite unsatisfactory : it says that unless you project the solution, you will not see a shift in the data, while linking to another answer which clearly states the opposite (between NAD27 to NAD83).

Comment: This doesn't explain the particular relationship between 4326 and 4269 : consider changing EPSG 4269 above to EPSG 4289 (Amersfoort datum), there will be a slight change in the lat/lon values instead of non.

Comment: I've added a bounty to the existing question to try and attract more attention.

Comment: I've added a possible answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304231/2856