# Special relationship between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4369

Tags: python, coordinate-system, datum, pyproj

This is a follow-up question to a previous one ([Projection between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4269 using pyproj does nothing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389929/projection-between-epsg4326-and-epsg4269-using-pyproj-does-nothing)).

When using pyproj (python 3.8.8 and pyproj 3.0.1 on windows) to project a point from EPSG:4326 (WGS84 Datum) to EPSG:4269 (NAD83 Datum), I obtain the exact same lat/lon. Howver, when projecting from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:4289 (Amersfoort Datum), there is a slight shift in the lat/lon values :

```
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform

crs_4326 = CRS("EPSG:4326")
crs_4269 = CRS("EPSG:4269")
crs_4289 = CRS("EPSG:4289")

transformer_4326_to_4269 = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from=crs_4326, crs_to=crs_4269).transform
transformer_4326_to_4289 = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from=crs_4326, crs_to=crs_4289).transform
p = Point(-118,33)  # some position in California
p1 = transform(transformer_4326_to_4269, p)
p2 = transform(transformer_4326_to_4289, p)

print(p)  # returns POINT (-118 33)
print(p1) # also returns POINT (-118 33)
print(p2) # returns POINT (-118.0045882781141 32.99426819423652)
```

Inspecting the EPSG codes on epsg.org, I see that these three datum have three different ellipsoids. Therefore, I expect to get different results for p and p1 since I do observe a difference between p and p2. What is the cause of this behaviour ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Projection between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4269 using pyproj does nothing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389929/projection-between-epsg4326-and-epsg4269-using-pyproj-does-nothing)

Comment: If you are in N. America NAD83 and WGS83 are almost exactly the same, on the other side of the planet there are larger differences. Equally, for the Amersfoort Datum there is a very small difference in the Netherlands, but a bigger one in the US/